# I have no idea how this is returning a nullPointerError

Tags: java, multidimensional-array

I'm using this class right here and attempting to call the .get() method on it.  This seems very simple but no matter what I change I get a nullPointerException on the line:

```
value = gameBoard[row-1][column-1];
```

It seems like it could be an off by one error but im almost positive the array is the right size and the .get method in the main method thats calling it starts with a row of 1 and a column of 1 so I can't see whats wrong...

```
public class Simple2DArray implements Simple2DInterface
{
public int[][] gameBoard;

public Simple2DArray(int aRow, int aColumn)
{

    int[][] gameBoard = new int[aRow][aColumn];
    for(int i=0;i<aRow;i++)
    {           
        for(int j=0;j<aColumn;j++)
        {           
            gameBoard[i][j] = -1;
        }
    }
}

public int getNumberOfRows()
{
    int rows;

    rows = gameBoard.length;

    return rows;
}

public int getNumberOfColumns()
{
    int columns;

    columns = gameBoard[0].length;

    return columns;     
}

public void clear()
{
    for(int i=0;i<gameBoard.length;i++)
    {
        for(int j=0;j<gameBoard[i].length;i++)
        {
            gameBoard[i][j] = -1;
        }
    }       
}

public void setToOne(int row, int column)
{
    gameBoard[row+1][column+1] = 1;
}

public void setToZero(int row, int column)
{
    gameBoard[row+1][column+1] = 0;
}

public void flip(int row, int column)
{
    if(gameBoard[row-1][column-1]==1)
    {
        gameBoard[row-1][column-1]=0;
    }
    if(gameBoard[row-1][column-1]==0)
    {
        gameBoard[row-1][column-1]=1;
    }
}

public int get(int row, int column)
{       
    int value;

    value = gameBoard[row-1][column-1];

    return value;
}
}
```

Comment: It may be unrelated, but why are the SetToOne/SetToZero methods using row+1 and column+1 ?

Comment: They actually should have been row-1 and column-1.  This was becuase its being used for a game board which starts at 1,1 while the arrays obviously start at 0,0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are declaring a new variable in the constructor when you write

```
int[][] gameBoard = new int[aRow][aColumn];
```

Remove the declaration int[][], and it will refer to the instance variable:

```
gameBoard = new int[aRow][aColumn];
```

Also the inner loop in clear() method must have j++ .

Comment: Thank you!  I knew it must have been something simple just didn't realize I couldn't declare that twice